# Loop response object and show id and name out of it using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I would like help doing a for each loop in either JS or jquery that will log too console every id and name for each program in the below json response, how can i map this?

```
[Object, Object]
    0:Object
    program: Object
    id:"001"
    name:"program001"
    1:Object
    program: Object
    id:"002"
    name:"program002"
```

Response Screen: http://postimg.org/image/o3aljrxnv/b7daaf20/

Thanks

Comment: Please consider browsing http://stackoverflow.com/help for infomation on how to improve your question.

Comment: The response syntax must be the above, can you map for the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, first of all as I can see in the question your response is similar to the below ***response*** variable: -

```
var response = [ { program: { id:"001", name:"program001"}}, { program: {  id:"002",  name:"program002" }}];
// where {} stands for some empty object.

for (var i =0 ;i < response.length; i++ ){
console.log(" ID :" + response[i].program.id+ " and Name :" + response[i].program.name ); //this will show id and name respectively
}
```

***hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: this returns undefined as it doesn't match the syntax of my response above?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
var foo = [ {id: 1, name: 'Nick'}, {id: 2, name: 'Peter'} ];

foo.forEach(function (item) {
  console.log('id is', item.id, ' and name is ', item.name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Solution:

```
$.each(json, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value.id, value.name);
});
```

See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for more info.